# Kerberos - Wireless clients not loading all kerberos tickets from domain

Tags: kerberos

We use a kerberos (http) ticket to access the internet via a supplied proxy (filtering) service.
When this was first installed all clients (pc's laptops etc) connected fine.
We have come up with error...
Some laptops get taken home and join home networks - but when they return to work the next day they dont work on the internet. When we run klist the http kerberos ticket is missing.
Our supplier tells us to remove the device from the domain and recreate the user, which is fine and fixes the issue. But as soon as the laptop goes home the same thing happens again.
When we complain to our supplier they just say there is an issue with your server (windows 2016) not issuing kerberos tickets.
Why would everything work until the device goes home
really need help

Answer (score 1):

When the laptops come back to work you don't need to leave the domain and re-join it.  Simply do two things:

In a CMD window run this command:  *klist purge*

Then clear the web browser cache

Try it again